# fullcalendar, failure parsing json

Tags: php, codeigniter, fullcalendar

im making a website for record attendance. i got attendance table with columns(attendanceid, employeeid(FK), date, clock_in, clock_out), im already make function so i can insert data but i can't display it as a event in fullcalendar.

MODEL

```
public function getAttendanceRecords($employeeid) {
        $q = $this->builder->select('at.*, em.empid')
            ->join('msemployee as em', 'em.empid = at.employeeid')
            ->where('at.employeeid', $employeeid)    
            ->get()->getResultArray();

        foreach($q as $records) {
            $format[] = [
           'id' => $records['attendanceid'],
           'title' => 'Attendance',
           'start' => $records['date'] . 'T' . $records['clock_in'],
           'end' => ($records['clock_out'] != null) ? $records['date'] . 'T' . $records['clock_out'] : null,
           'allDay' => true
            ];
        }
        return $format;
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function showRecords() {
        $employeeid = getSession('empid');
        $data['events'] = $this->attendance->getAttendanceRecords($employeeid);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('fullCalendar');
            var tanggal = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'prev,next'
                },
                editable: false,
                eventDisplay: 'block',
                events: {
                    url: '<?= current_url(true) ?>/calendar',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                },
                eventClick: function(info) {
                    let eventObj = info.event;
                    if(eventObj) {
                        modalForm(
                            'Attendance',
                            'modal-md',
                            '<?= base_url('attendance/form') ?>'
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
            tanggal.render();
        }, 200);
    });
```

and here is my json output
`{"events":[{"id":"28","title":"Attendance","start":"2024-03-05T14:50:38","end":null,"allDay":true}]}`

im really blind what's going on and i don't know what i have to do

Comment: Are you getting any related errors or warnings in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"events":[{"id":"28","title":"Attendance","start":"2024-03-05T14:50:38","end":null,"allDay":true}]}
```

needs to be

```
[{"id":"28","title":"Attendance","start":"2024-03-05T14:50:38","end":null,"allDay":true}]}{"events":[{"id":"28","title":"Attendance","start":"2024-03-05T14:50:38","end":null,"allDay":true}]
```

fullCalendar can't find events inside a sub-section of the JSON, it needs to be an array at the top level

I think you can fix this by changing

```
$data['events'] = $this->attendance->getAttendanceRecords($employeeid);
```

to

```
$data = $this->attendance->getAttendanceRecords($employeeid);
```

Reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array